# Django admin.py: save_model() is not called by model.save() in save method of ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

My blog post model has a many-to-many field for tags:

```
tags = models.ManyToManyField(PostTag)
```

But it was uncomfortable to edit it and I modified my model like this:

```
def _get_tagging(self): # Returns comma separated list of tags
    tagging = []
    for tag in self.tags.all():
        tagging.append(tag.name)
    return ", ".join(tagging)

def _set_tagging (self, tagging): # Saves tags from comma separated list
    tagging = tagging.split(", ")
    self.tags.clear()
    for tag in tagging:
        if len(tag) < 1:
            continue
        try:
            self.tags.add(PostTag.objects.get(name=tag))
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            self.tags.create(name=tag)

tagging = property(_get_tagging, _set_tagging)
```

Then I modified my `admin.py`:

```
class BlogAdminForm (forms.ModelForm):
    tagging = forms.CharField(required=False, label="Tags", max_length=200,
                        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'vTextField'}))

    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BlogAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if kwargs.has_key('instance'):
            instance = kwargs['instance']
            self.initial['tagging'] = instance.tagging

    def save(self, commit=True):
        model = super(BlogAdminForm, self).save(commit=False)
        model.tagging = self.cleaned_data["tagging"]

        if commit:
            model.save()

        return model
```

And this worked fine, but only for editing objects. I got an error when I tried to create a new object. Why? Because a many-to-many relationship can be used with an object that is not yet in the database and doesn't have a primary key ('BlogPost' instance needs to have a primary key value before a many-to-many relationship can be used). I tried to solve it by editing the save method in this way:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    model = super(BlogAdminForm, self).save(commit=False)
    try:
        model.tagging = self.cleaned_data["tagging"]
    except ValueError:
        model.save()
        model.tagging = self.cleaned_data["tagging"]

    if commit:
        model.save()
```

This resolved the original problem. But now `model.save()` doesn't call the `save_model` method of my admin model:

```
class BlogAdmin (admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ... 
    form = BlogAdminForm

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.author = request.user
        obj.save()
```

In consequence of this I get a new error: `null value in column "author_id" violates not-null constraint.` What am I doing wrong? Can I call this method manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to have to save the tags after you save the instance, and that means doing it in your `save_model` function. This is nothing to do with your tag-manipulation code: if you look at the [documentation for the `Form.save` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) it says:

> Another side effect of using `commit=False` is seen when your model has a many-to-many relation with another model. If your model has a many-to-many relation and you specify `commit=False` when you save a form, Django cannot immediately save the form data for the many-to-many relation. This is because it isn't possible to save many-to-many data for an instance until the instance exists in the database.
>
> To work around this problem, every time you save a form using `commit=False`, Django adds a `save_m2m()` method to your `ModelForm` subclass. After you've manually saved the instance produced by the form, you can invoke `save_m2m()` to save the many-to-many form data.

There are a couple of ways to solve your problem. You could write a [widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/widgets/) that converts back and forth between lists of tag ids and comma-separated tag names, and then call `form.save_m2m()` in your `save_model` method. But this approach has the disadvantage that you'll have to create new tags when decoding the value from the widget, even if the form is not saved (perhaps because of a validation error elsewhere in the form).

So I think a better approach in this case is to add your own `save_tags` method to the form:

```
class BlogAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    tagging = forms.CharField(required=False, label="Tags", max_length=200,
                              widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'vTextField'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Post

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BlogAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'instance' in kwargs:
            tags = (t.name for t in kwargs['instance'].tags.all())
            self.initial['tagging'] = ', '.join(tags)

    def save_tags(self, obj):
        obj.tags = (Tag.objects.get_or_create(name = tag.strip())[0]
                    for tag in self.cleaned_data['tagging'].split(','))

class BlogPostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = BlogAdminForm

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.author = request.user
        obj.save()
        form.save_tags(obj)
```

Note that I moved the tag-manipulation code to the form: I think it belongs here, and not in the model, because it's all about user input. I also made a couple of stylistic improvements:

- `'instance' in kwargs` is simpler than `kwargs.has_key('instance')`.
- The generator expression `(t.name for t in kwargs['instance'].tags.all())` is simpler than building a list in a `for` loop.
- The [`get_or_create` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get_or_create) is a handy shortcut that avoid the need to `try: ... except ObjectDoesNotExist: ...`
- You can assign directly to a `ManyToMany` field instead of calling `clear` and then `add` (also, it's more efficient when the tags don't change).

Comment: Thank you very much for such a great answer! Also thanks for stylistic improvements. I will take them into account in my work.